# save png in camera roll

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imageview

Is it possible to save images in camera roll as .PNG file ?

As far as I understand when we are using Mediastore class all files are saving as JPEG format.

The problem came when downloading transparent file and saved it to camera roll which is transparent png file and in camera roll it shows black jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that in a second step with Bitmap.compress

```
boolean compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality, OutputStream stream)
```

By passing an output stream for example a FileOutputStream:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, your_quality_from_1_to_100, out);
```

and then

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), absoluteFilepath, fileName, fileDescription);
```

For more information give a look to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

Comment: yeah it is creating png file but does not appear on camera roll, to show on camera roll you have to write more code...

Comment: you mean MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), absoluteFilepath, fileName, fileDescription);